# Auto resize Web Page issue in android 

Tags: android, resize, html

I am developing a website for mobile.  I have a resizing problem on
Android. On Iphone, IPad, Windows Mobile my site is automatically
resize.On Android, my page is resized only if the url looks like this:
www.mysite.ch. If the url looks like this: http://mobile.mysite.ch, my
page does not resize correctly. Do you know the problem?

I used bellow "viewport" meta tag,But it doesn't solve my problem

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Can you help me? Have you a work around for this problem ?